# How do I fill an array with natural numbers in c?

Tags: arrays, c, count

This is my code:

```
int i=1 , j=1 ,k=0, n=1;

printf("\nPut in number n which is the upper limit: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
bool *eratos = malloc(sizeof(n));
for (int m = 1; m<=n; m++) {
    printf("%d,", m);
    eratos[m] = m;
    printf("%d,", eratos[m]);
}
```

For some reason it does not fill up the eratos[m] array with numbers from 1 to 50 but only withs ones.

This is my output:

> 1,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,7,1,8,1,9,1,10,1,11,1,12,1,13,1,14,1,15,1,16,1,17,1,18,1,19,1,20,1,21,1,22,1,23,1,24,1,25,1,26,1,27,1,28,1,29,1,30,1,31,1,32,1,33,1,34,1,35,1,36,1,37,1,38,1,39,1,40,1,41,1,42,1,43,1,44,1,45,1,46,1,47,1,48,1,49,1,50,1

The first line of `printf()` is to check whether its counting up correctly, which it does obviously. But the array gets only filled up with ones and not with `[1,2,3…50]`.

Comment: `bool *eratos = malloc(sizeof(n))` ==> `bool *eratos = malloc(n * sizeof *eratos);`

Comment: Array indexes go from `0` to `N - 1`, not from `1` to `N`

Comment: *it does not fill up the `eratos[m]` array with numbers from 1 to 50 but only withs ones* is because it is a `bool` array, containing `0` and `1` only. All non-0 values are `true` (`1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a `bool` cannot hold anything apart from a `0` and `1`. To have values other than that, use `int` type.

That said, the next problem is in the memory allocation, you need to allocate appropriate amount of memory, i.e., the amount (value) held by `n`, not equal to the size of the variable `n` itself.

```
  int *eratos = malloc(n * sizeof(*eratos));
```

Finally, you need to correct your for loop to avoid off by one error, like

```
for (int m = 0; m < n; m++) { // C arrays use 0-based-indexing
  printf("%d,", m+1);         // still counts from 1, for sake of printing
```

Answer (score 0):

Another issue apart from the issue pointed out by SouravGosh is you have taken the `bool` array.

```
bool *eratos = malloc(sizeof(n));
eratos[m] = m;
```

Any non zero value is `true` in case of `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

And anther issue is that array indexes start at **0**, not at 1. Do:

```
for (int m = 0; m < n; m++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have *multiple* problems in your code.

- First you say that `eratos` is a pointer to `bool` when you seem to want an array of `int`.

  This is solved by changing the type to pointer to `int`:

  ```
   int *eratos = ...;
  ```
- Then since `n` is an `int`, `sizeof(n)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`, which is typically equal to `4`. That is, you only allocate four bytes for your array.

  You need to allocate `n` elements, which is `n` multiplied by the size of each element (which would be `sizeof *eratos`):

  ```
   int *eratos = malloc(n * sizeof *eratos);
  ```
- Lastly, remember that array indexes in C are *zero* based, which means an array of `n` elements will have indexes from `0` to `n - 1` (inclusive). Which means `eratos[m]` *will* go out of bounds (when `m == n`).

  This can be solved in two ways:

  1. Either subtract `1` for the array index:

     ```
      for (int m = 1; m <= n; ++m)
      {
          eratos[m - 1] = m;
      }
     ```
  2. Or loop from `0` to `n - 1` and add `1` to `m` to get the "natural number":

     ```
      for (int m = 0; m < n; ++m)
      {
          eratos[m] = m + 1;
      }
     ```

---

On an unrelated note, if you're only supposed to print the numbers between `1` and `n` (inclusive) then you don't need the array, only a single `printf` statement in the loop:

```
for (int m = 1; m <= n; ++m)
{
    printf("%d,", m);
}
```

Comment: I need the array for further working. I still don’t get it why the array sticks to 1.

Answer (score 0):

For starters this memory allocation

```
bool *eratos = malloc(sizeof(n));
```

does not make a sense. The expression `sizeof( n )` is equal to the expression `sizeof( int )` and does not depend on the value stored in the variable `n`.

You declared an array with the element type `bool` that is an alias for the type `_Bool`. Any non-zero value is converted to the value `1`.

Also this loop

```
for (int m = 1; m<=n; m++) {
    printf("%d,", m);
    eratos[m] = m;
    printf("%d,", eratos[m]);
}
```

invokes undefined behavior because the valid range of indices for an array with n elements is `[0, n)`.

It seems what you need is the following

```
unsigned int n = 1;

printf("\nPut in number n which is the upper limit: ");
scanf("%u", &n);

unsigned int *eratos = malloc( n * sizeof( unsigned int ) );

for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
{
    printf("%u,", i + 1 );
    eratos[i] = i + 1;
    printf("%u,", eratos[i]);
}
```